# struct type is not visible in ContentView

Tags: swiftui

I have a project that with the following structure:

```
KittenBase
  Resources
    kittens.json
  Models
    Kitten.swift
    Data.swift
  AppDelegate.swift
  SceneDelegate.swift
  ContentView.swift
```

and ContentView.swift looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var kitten : Kitten
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(kitten : kittenData[0])
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the compiler says that `Kitten` is an unresolved type and that kittenData is an unresolved variable. Here is the contents of Data.swift where I create the kittenData array:

```
let kittenData: [Kitten] = load("kittens.json")
func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

Why can't I access the Kitten type and the kittenData variable? 
Even more interestingly, If I copy the Kitten struct into the ContentView the compiler tells me it's an ambiguous reference, meaning it definitely KNOWS that Kitten.swift exists?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in XCode11 that was fixed when I  restarted my computer.

Comment: I had an issue which was similar enough to this to lead me here, and the restarting just Xcode was sufficient.